# Rails - Passing parameters to create filled in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameter-passing, link-to

I want to pass some parameters with link_to method to create method, so that the form will shown prefilled to a user.

I wrote this code to pass the parameters,

```
<%= link_to "Buy", new_transaction_url(:friend_id => @friend.id, :t_type => 2) %>
```

And in transactions_controller's new method, I have:

```
@transaction = Transaction.new
@transaction.t_type = params[:t_type]
```

It didn't work as well.

That would be great if you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually `new_transaction_url` would call the `#new` action in your controller, not the `#create` action.  Watch your log file while you do it to see exactly what controller action is being called and what parameters are being passed.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I made a mistake, I wrote this code inside the new method. And it's not working.

Comment: Then we need to know what exactly isn't working?  What's the log file say is being passed?

Comment: It doesn't show any errors:
Started GET "/transactions/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-15 04:23:46 +0100
Processing by TransactionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Friend Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "friends".* FROM "friends" WHERE "friends"."user_id" = 1

Comment: Ok.  So what isn't happening that you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try change `params[:t_type]` to `params[:transaction][:t_type]`.